# Populate text boxes from SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, textbox, populate

I have seven fields that need to be populated in seven text boxes. The data is coming from a SQL Compact DB...

Here's my code so far, but I'm stuck. What do I need to do to populate the text boxes on Form Load... thanks much.

Woody

```
private void mcContactSubmit_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Setup our SQL connection.
    SqlCeConnection dataSource = new SqlCeConnection(
                 @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\..\..\ContactInformation.sdf;
               Persist Security Info=False");
        SqlCeDataReader myReader = null;

    // Create our command text.
    string sqlQuery = String.Format(@"SELECT TOP (1) FirstName, LastName, Title, 
    Department, Category, Phone, Comments FROM ContactInformation 
    ORDER BY FirstName DESC");

    // Open the SQL connection.
    dataSource.Open();

    SqlCeCommand myCommand = new SqlCeCommand(sqlQuery, dataSource);
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use the index or the column name to get the actual data, as follows:

```
myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

// Run through the results
while (myReader.Read())
{
    string fname = myReader.GetString(0);

    // or alternatively:

    string fname2 = myReader["FirstName"];

    // Either of these should work
}
```

After which, it's simple assignment to the `TextBox`. Otherwise you could also directly insert the Data into the `TextBox`, but rather not as validation should be done before this in most cases.

If you need more help, have a look here:

[MSDN - SqlCeDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcedatareader(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Doh. I spoke too soon. The text boxes aren't being populated... here's what I'm seeing in debug mode:

Message "SQL Server Compact does not support calls to HasRows property if the underlying cursor is not scrollable."

What the heck does that mean?! LOL...

Comment: I've tried testing for rows right after myReader = cmd. ..., however, the error is thrown right before it. If I try to test it any earlier in the code, I get an Object is not set to a reference of an object error...

Comment: You'll just have to check the DataSet before, so do a bool whatever = myReader.Read(); and if it's false, don't fill the text boxes. Im not sure what that error means and am following Marc Gravell's advice with checking the Reader.